# Google access token does not contain name fields in some of the SAME requests for cypress with google-auth-library

Tags: node.js, google-api, cypress, google-oauth, google-auth-library

We try to load user profiles in a Node.JS backend via Google Oauth and login button.

Google Button login works correctly, the given access token credential is sent to the backend and `google-auth-library`'s `client.verifyIdToken` decodes the data correctly, and all the fields are there for the given scopes:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`

But when testing in Cypress with we can't click the login button and authenticate the user so we do the following:

1. Created a `refresh_token` in [Google Oauth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) for the given test user

Then for each test case runs:

2. Called `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` with the following body:

   - client_id
   - client_secret
   - grant_type: `refresh_token`
   - refresh_token
3. Sent the `access_token` from the response the same way as the google button login to the backend

For some of the first requests it works, after that the name stops apperaing in the decoded payload by `google-auth-library`'s `client.verifyIdToken`. (And using the access token in `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo` it returns the name field.)

Why is this happenning, are we missing on something, or should we do something in a different way to simulate user logins in cypress? If possible we don't want to add an extra `/v3/userinfo` call on the backend because the button login works without that.

We tried with different `/token` endpoints, or adding openid or other scopes too to the refresh token, but none of them worked.